# ¿Como cambio cada caracter numérico de string a diferentes int? C++

Tags: c++, string

Pongamos que tenemos un string llamado "strnum" que es '54321' y queremos pasar cada caracter a distintas variables int llamadas intnum[], es decir:

```
intnum[0] = 5
intnum[1] = 4
...
```

Para ello utilizaremos un for() para asignar cada valor, el problema es el siguiente:

Cuando pasamos un único caracter del string mediante atoi(), da un error diciendo que no se puede convertir const char en char, que debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es una función de transformación. La cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) de C++ dispone de una función para ello:

#### [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Esta función aplica una función a un rango y guarda el resultado en otro rango.

Así que si tenemos una cadena de caracteres:

```
std::string strnum = "54321";
```

Y queremos guardarlo en otro contenedor, podemos hacerlo así:

```
std::string strnum = "54321";
std::vector<int> num;

std::transform(strnum.begin(), strnum.end(),
               std::back_inserter(num),
               [](char c){ return c - '0'; });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eDiydZOcBUKC0C6d).

#### ¿Cómo funciona?

Para añadir datos a un `std::vector` vacío, deben insertarse en el mismo; normalmente usaríamos la función `std::vector::push_back`, pero al estar usando un algoritmo no podemos. Por suerte existe una herramienta de ayuda que si le pasamos un contenedor, llamará a `CONTENEDOR::push_back` por nosotros, esta utilidad es [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Cada caracter tiene un valor numérico, como puede verse en la [Tabla ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII):
[image]

El caracter `'0'` tiene el valor `48`, por lo tanto si restamos `'0'` a `'0'` obtenemos `0`, y esa es la función de transformación que usamos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo estás enfocando mal.

Los ordenadores no trabajan con *caracteres*, trabajan **con códigos de caracter**. Si estás en un sistema medianamente moderno, estará usando UTF-8, cuyos 127 primeros códigos son, *tal cual*, la [tabla ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Por lo tanto, para pasar de un carácter a un número, basta con realizar una simple resta:

```
intnum[0] = strnum[0] - 48;
intnum[1] = strnum[1] - 48;
...
```

Listo, los `char` se *promocionan* a `int` *automágicamente*, no hay que hacer ningún invento raro :-)